# Find the subgroup $H=<x,y>$ in the following cases.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to solve questions about cyclic groups.

In each case, find the subgroup $H=<x,y>$ of $G$:

1) $G=<a>$ is cyclic,  $x= a^3$ & $y=a^4$.

2) $G=<a>$ is cyclic,  $x= a^6$ & $y=a^8$.

3) $G=<a>$ is cyclic,  $x= a^m$ & $y=a^n$;        $gcd(m,n)=d$.

4) $G= S_3$, $x=(12)$ & $y=(23)$.

After calculation in part $(4)$, I found that $H=$ { (1), (12), (23), (13), (123), (132)}.

But regarding the first 3 parts, is there a rule including the $gcd$?  Like $<a^m,a^n>$= $<a^{gcd(m,n)}>$ ? I think one needs more information about $G$ ( finite, infinite). Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: You're right: $\;\langle a^m, a^n\rangle=\langle a^{\gcd(m,n)}\rangle$ . You can see it with *Bézout's identity*. That said, for me, ‘cyclic’ includes ‘finite’. If it's infinite, it's called a *monogeneous* group.

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)